# How to propagate japanese maple from this street (mutant?) specimen?

Tags: propagation, japanese-maple

There is a neatly pruned japanese maple in a public area close to my work:

[image]

We had warmer than usual weather last several weeks, and new growth appeared:

[image]

It is hard to believe, but this new branch was not there three weeks ago:

[image]

Is it possible to cut these young branches, and get a similar maple elsewhere one day?

NOTE: Looking more carefully, it occurs to me that this may be some kind of reverse mutation, no? But even the 'reversed' version looks attractive to me.

Comment: Is it a graft? It can be that the new leaves are from another graft than the red leaves are from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could propagate this Japanese maple, but now is not the right time for cuttings. If this tree produces seeds, use them instead, I think the success rate will be higher. I have tried summer cuttings once, but failed, so in my opinion it is not so easy. There are descriptions [here](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/start-cutting-japanese-maple-tree-41878.html), where they explain how to do this. However, I failed, probably because I had no time to mist the cuttings daily.

Furthermore, your tree in question seems to be grafted, and the shoots that you call mutant are probably from the original plant. This plant has larger leaves and might be less attractive (aesthetically).

Comment: But I can't wait till summer, since the tree will be pruned soon by person who maintains it. At least those larger branches will not be available Grin

Comment: You can try [hardwood cuttings](https://deepgreenpermaculture.com/diy-instructions/propagating-hardwood-cuttings/), but then you don't want the fresh shoots, but a little bit more woody material. You'll have to wait until the leaves fall off.